# how to compute this complex integral with high order polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Compute
>   $$
> \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=R} \frac{(2z^2+z-1)P'(z)}{P(z)+3}dz
> $$
>   where $P(z)=z^{10}+2z^9+z^5+1$.

It seems like I may use residue but it contains too  high order polynomials to do that efficiently? How should I do it instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Q(z)=P(z)+3=z^{10}+2z^9+z^5+4$. We have:
$$\lim_{R\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}(2z^2+z-1)\frac{Q'(z)}{Q(z)}\,dz=\sum_{\xi\in Z}(2\xi^2+\xi-1) $$
where $Z$ is the set of zeroes of $Q(z)$. Since, by Viète's theorem,
$$\sum_{\xi\in Z}\xi = -2,\qquad  \sum_{\xi\in Z}\xi^2 = (-2)^2-2\cdot 0 =4,$$
we simply have:
$$\lim_{R\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}(2z^2+z-1)\frac{Q'(z)}{Q(z)}\,dz = 8-2-10 = \color{red}{-4}.$$

Comment: I`m sorry... but I can`t understand how that sigma appear. Can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: @mikekim  Are you aware of the theorem for which $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)}\,dz $$ gives the number of zeroes of $P(z)$ inside the disk $|z|\leq R$? This is just a little variant.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any way, before you start you have to check that zeros of $2z^2 + z - 1$ and zeros of $Q'(z)$ are not zeros of $Q(z)$.